# CSV file with multiple events with different headers and numbers of values in a row

Tags: python, csv, datetime, dataset

So I have a very long csv file in this format below, these are the first two events of about 3000. The first row is date, detected with instrument number 16 (yes=16/no=0), detected with instrument number 17 (yes=17/no=0), and confidence of detection. Then the single value is the number of data points collected for that event. Then it goes into the actual data from that event, time in UTC, lat, lon, energy. My goal is for these 3000 events is to integrate all the energies (the light curve) to get a total energy. I need a way for my code to read the first value as a date and start a new "loop" to: read the next line so it integrates the next n events, print this integrate value, then recognize the next line as a time and do it again so I have 3000 integrated energies. I haven't really worked with a csv like this, especially without headers, so any start point is much appreciated!!

```
2021-10-15T16:49:30.059Z,16,0,medium
118
1634316570059,-77.00921630859375,36.263389587402344,3.0848139228168667e-15
1634316570061,-77.00920104980469,36.26337432861328,2.184921944046166e-15
1634316570063,-77.00919342041016,36.26335906982422,2.484885936969733e-15
1634316570065,-77.0091781616211,36.263343811035156,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570067,-77.00916290283203,36.26332473754883,2.084933946404977e-15
1634316570069,-77.00917053222656,36.2632942199707,3.584753911022812e-15
1634316570071,-77.0091781616211,36.263267517089844,2.8848379275344887e-15
1634316570073,-77.00918579101562,36.263240814208984,2.184921944046166e-15
1634316570075,-77.00919342041016,36.26321029663086,3.3847779157404337e-15
1634316570077,-77.00920104980469,36.26319122314453,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570079,-77.00920867919922,36.26319885253906,2.8848379275344887e-15
1634316570081,-77.00921630859375,36.263206481933594,3.1848019204580557e-15
1634316570083,-77.00921630859375,36.26321792602539,4.2846698945111345e-15
1634316570085,-77.00922393798828,36.26322555541992,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570087,-77.00922393798828,36.26323699951172,3.8847179039463786e-15
1634316570089,-77.00921630859375,36.26326370239258,4.6846218850758904e-15
1634316570091,-77.00920867919922,36.2632942199707,4.984585877999457e-15
1634316570093,-77.00920867919922,36.26332092285156,4.2846698945111345e-15
1634316570095,-77.00920104980469,36.26335144042969,4.984585877999457e-15
1634316570097,-77.00919342041016,36.26337814331055,4.4846458897935125e-15
1634316570099,-77.00918579101562,36.263389587402344,5.184561873281835e-15
1634316570101,-77.00917053222656,36.263404846191406,4.0846938992287565e-15
1634316570103,-77.00916290283203,36.26342010498047,4.7846098827170794e-15
1634316570105,-77.0091552734375,36.26343536376953,4.6846218850758904e-15
1634316570107,-77.00914764404297,36.26344680786133,3.8847179039463786e-15
1634316570109,-77.0091552734375,36.263431549072266,2.8848379275344887e-15
1634316570111,-77.0091552734375,36.26342010498047,2.284909941687355e-15
1634316570113,-77.0091552734375,36.263404846191406,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570115,-77.0091552734375,36.26339340209961,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634316570147,-77.0092544555664,36.26349639892578,3.2847899180992447e-15
1634316570149,-77.0092544555664,36.263450622558594,2.6848619322521108e-15
1634316570151,-77.00924682617188,36.263404846191406,2.384897939328544e-15
1634316570153,-77.00923919677734,36.26335906982422,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570155,-77.00923156738281,36.26331329345703,2.384897939328544e-15
1634316570157,-77.00922393798828,36.263267517089844,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570159,-77.00922393798828,36.263275146484375,2.384897939328544e-15
1634316570161,-77.00921630859375,36.263282775878906,3.8847179039463786e-15
1634316570163,-77.00921630859375,36.26329040527344,3.7847299063051896e-15
1634316570165,-77.00920867919922,36.263301849365234,4.3846578921523235e-15
1634316570167,-77.00920867919922,36.263309478759766,4.984585877999457e-15
1634316570169,-77.00920867919922,36.263328552246094,5.584513863846591e-15
1634316570171,-77.00921630859375,36.26334762573242,5.68450186148778e-15
1634316570173,-77.00922393798828,36.263370513916016,6.384417844976103e-15
1634316570175,-77.00922393798828,36.263389587402344,5.484525866205402e-15
1634316570177,-77.00923156738281,36.26340866088867,5.884477856770158e-15
1634316570179,-77.00923919677734,36.26340866088867,5.784489859128969e-15
1634316570181,-77.0092544555664,36.26340103149414,5.084573875640646e-15
1634316570183,-77.00926208496094,36.263397216796875,5.084573875640646e-15
1634316570185,-77.00926971435547,36.26339340209961,4.4846458897935125e-15
1634316570186,-77.00928497314453,36.26338577270508,5.284549870923024e-15
1634316570189,-77.00926971435547,36.263389587402344,5.084573875640646e-15
1634316570191,-77.0092544555664,36.26339340209961,4.4846458897935125e-15
1634316570193,-77.00923919677734,36.263397216796875,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634316570194,-77.00922393798828,36.26340103149414,4.0846938992287565e-15
1634316570196,-77.00920104980469,36.263404846191406,4.5846338874347014e-15
1634316570199,-77.00921630859375,36.26340866088867,4.4846458897935125e-15
1634316570201,-77.00923156738281,36.26340866088867,3.3847779157404337e-15
1634316570202,-77.00923919677734,36.26340866088867,2.8848379275344887e-15
1634316570207,-76.9164047241211,36.26325988769531,2.7848499298932998e-15
1634316570209,-76.91639709472656,36.26325225830078,3.4847659133816226e-15
1634316570210,-76.91638946533203,36.26324462890625,4.7846098827170794e-15
1634316570212,-76.9163818359375,36.26323318481445,4.8845978803582684e-15
1634316570214,-76.91637420654297,36.26322555541992,5.884477856770158e-15
1634316570217,-76.9163589477539,36.26321792602539,6.68438183789967e-15
1634316570218,-76.91635131835938,36.26320266723633,6.984345830823237e-15
1634316570220,-76.91633605957031,36.263187408447266,7.784249811952749e-15
1634316570222,-76.91632080078125,36.2631721496582,7.984225807235127e-15
1634316570224,-76.91631317138672,36.26315689086914,1.0083973757700096e-14
1634316570226,-76.91629791259766,36.26314163208008,1.258367369872982e-14
1634316570228,-76.91632080078125,36.263145446777344,1.358355367514171e-14
1634316570230,-76.9163589477539,36.26315689086914,1.568330162560668e-14
1634316570232,-76.91639709472656,36.26316833496094,1.7183121590224513e-14
1634316570234,-76.91643524169922,36.263179779052734,1.8682941554842348e-14
1634316570236,-76.91647338867188,36.263187408447266,2.2082533474642773e-14
1634316570238,-76.91646575927734,36.2631950378418,2.528214939916082e-14
1634316570240,-76.91645050048828,36.26319885253906,2.5782089387366766e-14
1634316570242,-76.91642761230469,36.26319885253906,2.828178932839649e-14
1634316570244,-76.91641235351562,36.26320266723633,2.928166930480838e-14
1634316570246,-76.91638946533203,36.263206481933594,3.028154928122027e-14
1634316570248,-76.91637420654297,36.263214111328125,3.048152527650265e-14
1634316570250,-76.91636657714844,36.263221740722656,3.008157328593789e-14
1634316570252,-76.91635131835938,36.26322937011719,2.928166930480838e-14
1634316570254,-76.91633605957031,36.26323699951172,2.9881597290655514e-14
1634316570256,-76.91632843017578,36.26324462890625,3.148140525291454e-14
1634316570258,-76.91632843017578,36.26325225830078,3.298122521753237e-14
1634316570260,-76.91634368896484,36.263267517089844,3.248128522932643e-14
1634316570262,-76.9163589477539,36.26327896118164,3.198134524112048e-14
1634316570264,-76.91636657714844,36.26329040527344,3.238129723168524e-14
1634316570266,-76.9163818359375,36.263301849365234,3.1781369245838105e-14
1634316570268,-76.91638946533203,36.26329040527344,3.0781489269426215e-14
1634316570270,-76.91639709472656,36.26326370239258,3.148140525291454e-14
1634316570272,-76.9164047241211,36.263240814208984,3.228130923404405e-14
1634316570274,-76.91641235351562,36.263214111328125,3.348116520573832e-14
1634316570276,-76.91641998291016,36.263187408447266,3.498098517035615e-14
1634316570278,-76.91641998291016,36.26317596435547,3.348116520573832e-14
1634316570280,-76.91642761230469,36.263179779052734,3.108145326234978e-14
1634316570282,-76.91642761230469,36.263179779052734,2.918168130716719e-14
1634316570284,-76.91642761230469,36.26318359375,3.048152527650265e-14
1634316570286,-76.91642761230469,36.26318359375,3.148140525291454e-14
1634316570288,-76.91643524169922,36.26318359375,3.1781369245838105e-14
1634316570290,-76.91643524169922,36.26317596435547,3.048152527650265e-14
1634316570292,-76.91644287109375,36.26316833496094,3.238129723168524e-14
1634316570294,-76.91644287109375,36.26316452026367,3.128142925763216e-14
1634316570296,-76.91644287109375,36.26315689086914,2.9681621295373136e-14
1634316570298,-76.91643524169922,36.26316452026367,2.858175332132006e-14
1634316570300,-76.9164047241211,36.263179779052734,2.748188534726698e-14
1634316570302,-76.9163818359375,36.2631950378418,2.2582473462848718e-14
1634316570304,-76.91635131835938,36.263214111328125,1.9982785524177805e-14
1634316570306,-76.91632843017578,36.26322937011719,1.4983385642118356e-14
1634316570308,-76.91632843017578,36.26323699951172,1.2283709705806253e-14
1634316570310,-76.91636657714844,36.26323318481445,1.068390174354723e-14
1634316570312,-76.9164047241211,36.26322937011719,8.884117786005828e-15
1634316570314,-76.91644287109375,36.26322555541992,7.284309823746804e-15
1634316570316,-76.9164810180664,36.263221740722656,6.084453852052536e-15
1634316570318,-76.9164810180664,36.263221740722656,4.5846338874347014e-15
1634316570320,-76.91645050048828,36.26322937011719,2.384897939328544e-15
1634316570342,-76.91644287109375,36.26319122314453,2.7848499298932998e-15
1634316570344,-76.91645812988281,36.263179779052734,2.484885936969733e-15
2021-10-15T16:28:56.018Z,17,0,low
53
1634315336018,-163.02442932128906,16.354591369628906,1.485005960557843e-15
1634315336020,-163.0244140625,16.35460090637207,1.584993958199032e-15
1634315336022,-163.0244140625,16.354612350463867,1.984945948763788e-15
1634315336024,-163.0244140625,16.354623794555664,2.284909941687355e-15
1634315336026,-163.0244140625,16.35463523864746,1.884957951122599e-15
1634315336028,-163.02439880371094,16.354646682739258,2.084933946404977e-15
1634315336030,-163.0244140625,16.354642868041992,2.484885936969733e-15
1634315336032,-163.0244140625,16.35463523864746,2.6848619322521108e-15
1634315336034,-163.02442932128906,16.35462760925293,2.6848619322521108e-15
1634315336036,-163.02442932128906,16.354618072509766,2.6848619322521108e-15
1634315336038,-163.02444458007812,16.354610443115234,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634315336040,-163.02444458007812,16.354612350463867,2.484885936969733e-15
1634315336042,-163.02444458007812,16.354616165161133,2.384897939328544e-15
1634315336044,-163.02444458007812,16.35462188720703,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634315336046,-163.02444458007812,16.35462760925293,2.7848499298932998e-15
1634315336048,-163.02444458007812,16.354633331298828,3.2847899180992447e-15
1634315336050,-163.02444458007812,16.354637145996094,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634315336052,-163.0244598388672,16.35464096069336,3.1848019204580557e-15
1634315336054,-163.0244598388672,16.354642868041992,2.9848259251756777e-15
1634315336055,-163.02447509765625,16.354646682739258,3.3847779157404337e-15
1634315336058,-163.02447509765625,16.354650497436523,3.8847179039463786e-15
1634315336060,-163.02447509765625,16.354637145996094,4.5846338874347014e-15
1634315336062,-163.0244598388672,16.354618072509766,5.084573875640646e-15
1634315336063,-163.02444458007812,16.354597091674805,5.184561873281835e-15
1634315336066,-163.0244140625,16.354576110839844,5.68450186148778e-15
1634315336068,-163.02439880371094,16.354557037353516,5.68450186148778e-15
1634315336070,-163.0244140625,16.35456085205078,6.784369835540859e-15
1634315336071,-163.02442932128906,16.354576110839844,7.084333828464426e-15
1634315336073,-163.02444458007812,16.35459327697754,7.284309823746804e-15
1634315336076,-163.0244598388672,16.3546085357666,7.384297821387993e-15
1634315336078,-163.02447509765625,16.354623794555664,7.284309823746804e-15
1634315336079,-163.0244903564453,16.354625701904297,7.084333828464426e-15
1634315336081,-163.0244903564453,16.354618072509766,7.384297821387993e-15
1634315336083,-163.0244903564453,16.354612350463867,7.68426181431156e-15
1634315336086,-163.0244903564453,16.354604721069336,8.484165795441072e-15
1634315336087,-163.02447509765625,16.354597091674805,8.484165795441072e-15
1634315336089,-163.02447509765625,16.354597091674805,8.784129788364639e-15
1634315336091,-163.02447509765625,16.35460090637207,8.884117786005828e-15
1634315336093,-163.02447509765625,16.35460662841797,8.884117786005828e-15
1634315336095,-163.02447509765625,16.354610443115234,9.184081778929395e-15
1634315336097,-163.02447509765625,16.3546142578125,8.784129788364639e-15
1634315336099,-163.02447509765625,16.354612350463867,8.184201802517505e-15
1634315336101,-163.02447509765625,16.35460662841797,7.884237809593938e-15
1634315336103,-163.02447509765625,16.35460090637207,7.184321826105615e-15
1634315336105,-163.02447509765625,16.35459327697754,6.68438183789967e-15
1634315336107,-163.0244903564453,16.35458755493164,6.384417844976103e-15
1634315336109,-163.02447509765625,16.35458755493164,5.584513863846591e-15
1634315336111,-163.0244598388672,16.354595184326172,4.7846098827170794e-15
1634315336113,-163.02444458007812,16.35460090637207,3.8847179039463786e-15
1634315336115,-163.02444458007812,16.3546085357666,3.0848139228168667e-15
1634315336117,-163.02442932128906,16.354616165161133,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634315336119,-163.0244140625,16.354616165161133,2.084933946404977e-15
1634315336121,-163.0244140625,16.3546085357666,1.285029965275465e-15
2021-10-14T17:04:46.571Z,17,0,low
26
...
```

Update: formatting is different for events detected with both instruments 16 and 17 (see comment below for more info):

```
2021-10-14T10:16:07.969Z,16,17,medium
74
1634206567969,-87.70339965820312,-12.525328636169434,1.78496995348141e-15
1634206567971,-87.70339965820312,-12.525323867797852,1.584993958199032e-15
1634206567973,-87.70340728759766,-12.525325775146484,1.684981955840221e-15
1634206567975,-87.70341491699219,-12.525327682495117,1.884957951122599e-15
1634206567977,-87.70341491699219,-12.52532958984375,1.78496995348141e-15
1634206567979,-87.70342254638672,-12.525331497192383,1.584993958199032e-15
1634206567981,-87.70342254638672,-12.525333404541016,1.884957951122599e-15
1634206567983,-87.70341491699219,-12.525336265563965,1.984945948763788e-15
1634206567985,-87.70339965820312,-12.52534008026123,2.284909941687355e-15
1634206567987,-87.7033920288086,-12.52534294128418,1.984945948763788e-15
1634206567989,-87.70338439941406,-12.525346755981445,1.78496995348141e-15
1634206567991,-87.70337677001953,-12.525354385375977,1.684981955840221e-15
1634206567993,-87.70337677001953,-12.525372505187988,1.185041967634276e-15
1634206567997,-87.703369140625,-12.525408744812012,1.485005960557843e-15
1634206567999,-87.703369140625,-12.525426864624023,1.285029965275465e-15
1634206568007,-87.78045654296875,-12.52658462524414,1.78496995348141e-15
1634206568009,-87.78046417236328,-12.52658462524414,2.484885936969733e-15
1634206568011,-87.78047943115234,-12.526582717895508,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634206568013,-87.78047943115234,-12.526573181152344,3.0848139228168667e-15
1634206568015,-87.78048706054688,-12.526564598083496,3.584753911022812e-15
1634206568017,-87.78048706054688,-12.526555061340332,4.1846818968699455e-15
1634206568019,-87.7804946899414,-12.526545524597168,4.6846218850758904e-15
1634206568021,-87.7804946899414,-12.526537895202637,5.084573875640646e-15
1634206568023,-87.78048706054688,-12.526537895202637,5.284549870923024e-15
1634206568025,-87.78047943115234,-12.52653694152832,5.884477856770158e-15
1634206568027,-87.78047180175781,-12.526535987854004,6.984345830823237e-15
1634206568029,-87.78045654296875,-12.526535987854004,7.484285819029182e-15
1634206568031,-87.78044891357422,-12.526533126831055,7.984225807235127e-15
1634206568033,-87.78043365478516,-12.526520729064941,7.984225807235127e-15
1634206568035,-87.78042602539062,-12.526508331298828,7.784249811952749e-15
1634206568037,-87.78041076660156,-12.526495933532715,7.68426181431156e-15
1634206568039,-87.7803955078125,-12.526482582092285,7.884237809593938e-15
1634206568041,-87.78038787841797,-12.526473999023438,7.584273816670371e-15
1634206568043,-87.78040313720703,-12.526484489440918,7.084333828464426e-15
1634206568045,-87.7804183959961,-12.526494026184082,6.484405842617292e-15
1634206568047,-87.78043365478516,-12.526503562927246,5.284549870923024e-15
1634206568049,-87.78044891357422,-12.52651309967041,4.8845978803582684e-15
1634206568051,-87.78045654296875,-12.526520729064941,5.084573875640646e-15
1634206568053,-87.78045654296875,-12.52651596069336,4.7846098827170794e-15
1634206568055,-87.78045654296875,-12.526511192321777,4.3846578921523235e-15
1634206568057,-87.78045654296875,-12.526506423950195,4.4846458897935125e-15
1634206568059,-87.78045654296875,-12.526500701904297,3.8847179039463786e-15
1634206568060,-87.78045654296875,-12.526496887207031,3.0848139228168667e-15
1634206568063,-87.78046417236328,-12.52650260925293,3.0848139228168667e-15
1634206568065,-87.78047943115234,-12.526508331298828,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634206568067,-87.78048706054688,-12.52651309967041,1.984945948763788e-15
1634206568068,-87.78050231933594,-12.526518821716309,1.984945948763788e-15
1634206568071,-87.78050994873047,-12.526522636413574,1.684981955840221e-15
1634206568073,-87.780517578125,-12.526510238647461,1.584993958199032e-15
1634206568075,-87.780517578125,-12.526497840881348,2.184921944046166e-15
1634206568076,-87.780517578125,-12.526485443115234,2.5848739346109218e-15
1634206568078,-87.78052520751953,-12.526473045349121,2.7848499298932998e-15
1634206568081,-87.78052520751953,-12.52646255493164,3.0848139228168667e-15
1634206568083,-87.780517578125,-12.526474952697754,3.9847059015875675e-15
1634206568084,-87.78050994873047,-12.526488304138184,3.9847059015875675e-15
1634206568086,-87.78050231933594,-12.526501655578613,4.1846818968699455e-15
1634206568088,-87.78050231933594,-12.526514053344727,4.7846098827170794e-15
1634206568091,-87.7804946899414,-12.526527404785156,5.084573875640646e-15
1634206568093,-87.78048706054688,-12.526535987854004,5.184561873281835e-15
1634206568094,-87.78048706054688,-12.526544570922852,5.084573875640646e-15
1634206568096,-87.78048706054688,-12.5265531539917,5.384537868564213e-15
1634206568099,-87.78048706054688,-12.526561737060547,5.68450186148778e-15
1634206568101,-87.78047943115234,-12.526570320129395,5.284549870923024e-15
1634206568102,-87.78048706054688,-12.52657413482666,5.084573875640646e-15
1634206568104,-87.78048706054688,-12.526578903198242,4.7846098827170794e-15
1634206568106,-87.78048706054688,-12.526583671569824,4.984585877999457e-15
1634206568109,-87.7804946899414,-12.52658748626709,5.484525866205402e-15
1634206568110,-87.7804946899414,-12.526592254638672,6.784369835540859e-15
1634206568112,-87.78048706054688,-12.526575088500977,6.68438183789967e-15
1634206568114,-87.78048706054688,-12.526556968688965,5.884477856770158e-15
1634206568116,-87.78047943115234,-12.526538848876953,5.184561873281835e-15
1634206568118,-87.78047180175781,-12.526520729064941,3.584753911022812e-15
1634206568120,-87.78047180175781,-12.52650260925293,2.6848619322521108e-15
1634206568122,-87.78047943115234,-12.526507377624512,1.485005960557843e-15
51
1634206567977,-86.63197326660156,-12.489493370056152,4.984585877999457e-15
1634206567979,-86.63197326660156,-12.489490509033203,4.6846218850758904e-15
1634206567981,-86.6319808959961,-12.489486694335938,5.184561873281835e-15
1634206567983,-86.6319808959961,-12.489477157592773,5.184561873281835e-15
1634206567985,-86.63198852539062,-12.489458084106445,5.484525866205402e-15
1634206567987,-86.63199615478516,-12.489439964294434,6.184441849693725e-15
1634206567990,-86.63200378417969,-12.489420890808105,5.68450186148778e-15
1634206567991,-86.63201141357422,-12.489401817321777,4.984585877999457e-15
1634206567999,-86.63202667236328,-12.489419937133789,5.284549870923024e-15
1634206568001,-86.63203430175781,-12.48942756652832,4.4846458897935125e-15
1634206568005,-86.63209533691406,-12.489420890808105,5.784489859128969e-15
1634206568007,-86.63213348388672,-12.489412307739258,6.484405842617292e-15
1634206568009,-86.63217163085938,-12.48940372467041,7.68426181431156e-15
1634206568011,-86.63221740722656,-12.489395141601562,7.68426181431156e-15
1634206568013,-86.63224029541016,-12.48939323425293,8.784129788364639e-15
1634206568015,-86.63221740722656,-12.48940372467041,8.484165795441072e-15
1634206568017,-86.6322021484375,-12.48941421508789,9.484045771852962e-15
1634206568019,-86.6321792602539,-12.489424705505371,9.484045771852962e-15
1634206568021,-86.63216400146484,-12.489436149597168,8.484165795441072e-15
1634206568023,-86.63214874267578,-12.489445686340332,9.084093781288206e-15
1634206568025,-86.63213348388672,-12.489455223083496,1.0083973757700096e-14
1634206568027,-86.63212585449219,-12.48946475982666,1.2083733710523875e-14
1634206568029,-86.63211059570312,-12.489473342895508,1.1783769717600308e-14
1634206568031,-86.63209533691406,-12.489482879638672,1.1183841731753174e-14
1634206568033,-86.63208770751953,-12.489483833312988,1.1483805724676741e-14
1634206568035,-86.63208770751953,-12.48946475982666,1.0883877738829607e-14
1634206568037,-86.632080078125,-12.489446640014648,1.0483925748264851e-14
1634206568039,-86.632080078125,-12.48942756652832,9.084093781288206e-15
1634206568041,-86.632080078125,-12.489409446716309,8.58415379308226e-15
1634206568043,-86.63207244873047,-12.489396095275879,7.284309823746804e-15
1634206568045,-86.63207244873047,-12.489398002624512,5.084573875640646e-15
1634206568079,-86.7547607421875,-12.485508918762207,5.68450186148778e-15
1634206568081,-86.75476837158203,-12.485518455505371,5.484525866205402e-15
1634206568083,-86.75476837158203,-12.485527038574219,7.384297821387993e-15
1634206568085,-86.7547378540039,-12.485523223876953,5.984465854411347e-15
1634206568087,-86.75469970703125,-12.485518455505371,8.68414179072345e-15
1634206568089,-86.7432632446289,-12.516714096069336,1.0983865736470796e-14
1634206568091,-86.74429321289062,-12.513812065124512,1.1083853734111985e-14
1634206568093,-86.74303436279297,-12.517171859741211,1.2183721708165064e-14
1634206568095,-86.74327087402344,-12.516566276550293,1.2183721708165064e-14
1634206568097,-86.74252319335938,-12.518638610839844,1.2183721708165064e-14
1634206568099,-86.74343872070312,-12.516180038452148,1.168378171995912e-14
1634206568101,-86.74300384521484,-12.517393112182617,1.158379372231793e-14
1634206568103,-86.7431411743164,-12.517057418823242,1.1383817727035552e-14
1634206568105,-86.74283599853516,-12.517965316772461,9.983985760058907e-15
1634206568107,-86.74272155761719,-12.518328666687012,1.2083733710523875e-14
1634206568109,-86.7419204711914,-12.520586967468262,1.2783649694012198e-14
1634206568111,-86.7414321899414,-12.52199935913086,1.3783529670424088e-14
1634206568113,-86.74019622802734,-12.525436401367188,1.3683541672782899e-14
1634206568115,-86.74127960205078,-12.52233600616455,1.168378171995912e-14
1634206568117,-86.74078369140625,-12.523541450500488,9.68402176713534e-15
```

Comment: What do you mean by integrate?

Comment: I need to integrate all the energies (the last column) for a data set, so for the first one i need to integrate those 118 values for a total energy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know calculus, so I cannot help you with the integration, but here's how to parse that file and get a start on making sense of the data.

I'm using Python's standard CSV module.  It has a **reader** class which allows you to iterate through all the rows of a CSV.  There are two ways to step through the rows, and my code uses both:

- `for row in reader`: this automatically advances the reader, the reader signals when it's run out of rows and the loop exits
- `next(reader)`: this "manually advances" the reader one row

```py
import csv

# Will look like:
#   [
#     [
#       ['2021-10-15T16:49:30.059Z','16','0','medium'],
#       [
#         118 data-point rows (all values are strings)
#       ]
#     ],
#     next event
#    ]
data = []

with open('sample.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        header_row = row                     # first line of event
        data_points = int(next(reader)[0])   # second line, single integer count

        data_rows = []
        while len(data_rows) < data_points:  # loop through the right amount of data points
            try:
                data_row = next(reader)
            except StopIteration:
                print(f'error: for {header_row}, expected {data_points} data-point rows, but event only has {len(data_rows)} data-point rows')
                break

            data_rows.append(data_row)

        data.append([header_row, data_rows]) # glue it together


# Print out a sanity check to make sure that all worked
for datum in data:
    header_row = datum[0]
    data_rows = datum[1]

    event_date = header_row[0]
    print(f'Event on {event_date} has {len(data_rows)} data points')
```

I'm using the for-loop to control reading the file as a section of events:

1. In each section I start off with what I'm calling the "header row"
2. Next I advance one row and parse the number of data points for this event

   1. With the number of data point, I manually advance through that many data-point rows.
3. At the bottom of the loop I'm grouping the header row and all the accumulated data points into one list and appending it to `data`.

All that concludes a single event, and the for-loop does it all again for the next event, till there are no more events.

When I run that with your sample data, I get:

```
Event on 2021-10-15T16:49:30.059Z has 118 data points
Event on 2021-10-15T16:28:56.018Z has 53 data points
```

With that in place, you can now loop over events, and for each event loop over the data points, integrating along the way.

**Update 1**

An event has multiple sets of data-point rows.  I think the structure of my code still stands.

The main loop processes an "event"; inside each event you know there is a 1-column row that signals how many rows of data points follow.

I recommend taking a step back, make a much smaller example set of data that you can look at one glance, maybe 20 rows tops, and has all these characteristics.  Write down on paper what your *algorithm* is.

Something like: "I start at row 1, it must be an event header. I move to row 2, it must be the count of data-point rows that follow. I move on and process that many rows. I move on to the next row: is it single-column (a count of data-point rows to follow)? If so, run that inner data-point loop again. If not, this event is done, I go back to the top of the main loop for the next event."

Comment: Thank you so much! I have all the integration figured out for one single event, so once I can read multiple events from this huge dataset i can loop it!

Comment: Great! If this solution works for you, please accept it, the check mark ✅ under the number at the top of my post.

Comment: working on it now, so will do :) thanks again!

Comment: I get the stop iteration error for lines with next() even just with a few data sets

Comment: Try to isolate just the event and its data points that are causing the error. From what  I can read in my code, you'd only get StopIteration if the event says it has X data points but there are really less than X rows after that. I've updated the code to halt on that error and print a debug message.

Comment: I removed the last row from the last event of your sample, and now I get the error message, **error: for ['2021-10-15T16:28:56.018Z', '17', '0', 'low'], expected 53 data-point rows, but event only has 52 data-point rows**

Comment: So actually it's something to do with the data i have, If the same event was detected with both detector 16 and 17, it will have the first detection with the header ['2021-10-15T16:28:56.018Z', '17', '0', 'low], then 74 points, then the data for the first detection, then no header for the next detection for the same event, just 51 points and then the data points so it looks kind of like the answer I posted:

Comment: I see, I added a very high-level algorithm you can try to implement. Also, edit your original question with your new example of data.

Comment: Thank you, sorry new to actually asking questions here. I will give it a go later today and update! Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way that if the stopiteration is called, like you have outlined, that the previous header could be used for that event too? almost like: ... 1. stopiteration called 2. copy previous header for this event 3. loop through as per usual ? I just don't know if something like that is possible since its not explicitly in the actual csv

Comment: and also when i run the entire data set, once it hits that '51', it counts the rest of the data rows at the int number eg: Event on 2021-10-15T16:49:30.059Z has 118 data points
Event on 2021-10-15T16:28:56.018Z has 53 data points
,Event on 2021-10-14T17:04:46.571Z has 26 data points
,Event on 2021-10-14T10:16:07.969Z has 74 data points
,Event on 51 has 315343 data points

Comment: Hey, @kasiaw :) So, I'm kinda stumped on how to see you progress through this. StackOverflow is for specific questions, and this question has meandered a bit. At this point, I'd personally like to see that you've tried some of the code I've offered, and modified it on your own to try and address some of the problems you are facing.  Now that you know more about your data and the code, re-write this question...

Comment: Include a condensed example of the input. Take time to *craft* the minimum number of lines of CSV that represent your problem. I believe that by now, you can show us how much you understand of your "problem space" in less than 20 lines of CSV. Really work to remove as much of the data that isn't relevant, like all those 10+ digit floating point numbers, and show us what matters: "events", single-column counts of data-point rows, rows of "data points", etc... Also, include some of the code I've suggested, and that you've tried to modify to address the problem.

Comment: I'll continue to follow along and try to help :)

Comment: So should I make a new question then ? I'm seeing what my problem is, and I have an idea of how to fix it, but I am not the most experienced coder and I don't if my idea could work. I can make like a really simple csv to convey what i need

Comment: I was thinking you could edit this one. And trying ideas (and trying again and again) is a large part of coding :)